# Changing keyword defaults of a function in Python

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
def func_1(a, b=1, c=None):
     code here
```

Now I want to make another function that has the same internals but different keyword arguments.

```
def func_2(a, b=2, c='asdf'):
    code here
```

One option would be a closure like this:

```
 def make_func(b, c):
     def func(a, b=b, c=c):
         code here
     return func

 func_1 = make_func(1, None)
 func_2 = make_func(2, 'asdf')
```

Is there a more concise/Pythonic way to go about this?

Comment: Why use a closure? Just call one from the other: `def func_2(a, b=2, c='asdf'): func_1(a, b, c)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe: the closure acts as a factory to produce more such functions. I had made the same comment, then deleted it again once I realised that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters true, but generating the functions dynamically seems unnecessary for a small number (not to mention likely makes life harder for IDEs).

Comment: Or does the OP actually mean *changing*, i.e. altering the defaults in an existing function object, which isn't what the example does.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I meant making another function with same behavior, different keywords - sorry for ambiguous wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`functools.partial()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

func_2 = partial(func_1, b=2, c='asdf')
```

The defaults supplied to the partial can be overridden again when calling it:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def func_1(a, b=1, c=None):
...     return a, b, c
...
>>> func_2 = partial(func_1, b=2, c='asdf')
>>> func_2(42)
(42, 2, 'asdf')
>>> func_2(42, b=5, c='spam')
(42, 5, 'spam')
```